# Rolling dice until each has taken a specific value

Tags: probability, dice

I'm facing the following problem.

Let's say I have $N$ dice in hand. I need to calculate how much time I should roll my dice to make all of them equal to some selected (pre-defined) number. Each time I roll the selected number with some dice, I remove these dice from my hand and keep rolling the rest.

Example:
I have $2$ dice and I want to roll sixes. When I get one, I will remove this die and will roll one die instead of two. How many times do I need to roll my dice in order to get sixes in all (to make my hand empty)?

I suppose that the correct answer is (for two dice) ${1\over6} +{1\over6} + {1\over6}\times{1\over6}$, but it seems to be wrong because I tried to implement an algorithm to calculate the probability, in which I ran 1M continuous rolls to calculate the average amount of required rolls.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question has no well-defined answer in its present form, since the time it takes will obviously be different on different trials. In case you intended to ask about the expected value of the time it takes, this question has been asked before here but I couldn't find the duplicate.

Comment: No matter what value I'm trying to get. The result can be depends only on: amount of dices and size of the dices (d2..dN) but choosen value will always exists on all dices. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Sorry, that seems to be a misunderstanding. I wasn't saying that it matters which number on the dice you're waiting for. I was saying that it makes no sense to ask for the time it takes until you get that number on all dice, because that time will be different every time you do the experiment. A more meaningful question is what the expected value, that is, the average, of the required time is, and your last paragraph seems to suggest that this is what you in fact intended to ask about in the preceding paragraphs.

Comment: as @joriki i also think you're looking for the expected value, as it's theoretically possible to role the dices infinitely before a '6' appears...

Comment: you'd probably better re-tag the question to 'probability'

Comment: Thanks. I re-tag it to `probability`. If someone helps me to find probability I can find number of rolls (expected or approximated) ~ 100/Probability (the final answer, for example, 7.24 is fine). Thanks

Comment: For $N=2$, the expected duration is $\frac{96}{11}=8.\overline{72}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to interpret the question in a more formal way. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. geometric random variables with rate of success $p$ (which is $1/6$ in this case). Find $E[\max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}]$.

My approach is to first compute the distribution of $Y = \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$. Suppose $y \in \mathbb N$ is given.

\begin{align*}
P(Y \le y) & =
\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \le y) \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 - P(X_i > y)\right) \\
& = \left(1 - (1 - p)^y\right)^n \\
\therefore P(Y = y) & = (1 - (1 - p)^y)^n - (1 - (1 - p)^{y-1})^n.
\end{align*}
(Note that $P(Y = 1) = p^n$.)
For ease of writing, let $q = 1 - p$.
The expected value of $Y$ is
\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=1}^\infty yP(Y = y) & =
\sum_{y=1}^\infty y\left((1 - q^y)^n - (1 - q^{y-1})^n\right).
\end{align*}
This is the simplest expression I can find. There might be simpler ones, but I haven't found any.

Comment: thanks for your time! For 2 d6 dices the result is very close to: `p1+p2+p1*p2` and far away from computation. I hope I will get another one answer to get the same (almost the same) result to confirm answer

Comment: What are $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: probability to roll selected number on first and second die, i.e. p1=p2=1/6

Comment: I get $8.73$ as an approximation of the result from my series. Is that not close to your simulation?

Comment: my bad, i did a mistake in formula

Comment: @Tunococ: I believe that $(3)$ from my answer is the same as your answer. In $(9)$ from my answer, I give a much simpler form (a finite sum of $n$ terms).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be an $n$-tuple of integers. Using the Binomial Distribution on each die, we get the expected duration to be
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\sum_{\max(\alpha)=k-1}\left(\frac56\right)^\alpha\left(\frac16\right)^n\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\,\left[\frac{1-\left(\frac56\right)^k}{1-\frac56}\right]^{\,n}-\left[\frac{1-\left(\frac56\right)^{k-1}}{1-\frac56}\right]^{\,n}\,\right)\left(\frac16\right)^n\tag2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\left(\,\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right]^n-\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^{k-1}\right]^n\,\right)\tag3\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^Nk\left(\,\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right]^n-\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^{k-1}\right]^n\,\right)\tag4\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^Nk\,\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right]^n-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(k+1)\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right]^n\,\right)\tag5\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(N\,\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^N\right]^n-\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right]^n\,\right)\tag6\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1-\left[1-\left(\frac56\right)^k\right]^n\right)\tag7\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac56\right)^{jk}\tag8\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}}{1-\left(\frac56\right)^j}}\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: expected maximum duration of $n$ Binomial variables
$\phantom{(1)\text{:}}$ with termination probability $\frac16$
$(2)$: $\sum\limits_{\max(\alpha)\lt k}\left(\frac56\right)^\alpha=\left[\frac{1-\left(\frac56\right)^k}{1-\frac56}\right]^n$ and $\sum\limits_{\max(\alpha)=k-1}=\sum\limits_{\max(\alpha)\lt k}-\sum\limits_{\max(\alpha)\lt k-1}$
$(3)$: arithmetic
$(4)$: write infinite sum as a limit
$(5)$: prepare to telescope
$(6)$: cancel the telescoping terms
$(7)$: simplify and evaluate the limit
$(8)$: apply the Binomial Theorem
$(9)$: evaluate the geometric series

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you could use inclusion–exclusion: There are $n$ conditions for the dice to have rolled the desired number, the probability for $j$ particular conditions to be violated after $k$ steps is $\left(\frac56\right)^{jk}$, and there are $\binom nj$ ways to choose the conditions to violate, so the probability for the process not to have completed after $k$ steps is

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom nj\left(\frac56\right)^{jk}\;,
$$

and summing this for $k$ from $0$ to $\infty$ yields the expected time for the process to complete and confirms your result.

Comment: @joriki: This is a nice short cut to $(8)$. When I got to $(8)$, I should have noticed that it was in the form for a simple application of inclusion-exclusion, but I was so close to getting the "closed form" that I got distracted. Thanks.